# Example of expression evaluating to an lvalue

Tags: c++

Is there any expression that can be evaluated to give an lvalue? I believe expressions yield an rvalue which can be assigned to an lvalue.

Answer (score 7):

If you have `x[y] = z;`, `x[y]` is the lvalue and `z` is the rvalue. Clearly `x[y]` is an expression, and it can be evaluated. Therefore it can be evaluated to give an lvalue.

Answer (score 2):

Gabe is correct, but more specifically, any expression that results in a reference is an lvalue. But that's not all, pointer deferences and array access are both expressions that result in an lvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Another example would be a function that returns a reference, i.e. `std::vector`'s index operator (`reference operator[]( size_type n`) so you can do something like this:

```
std::vector< Z > vector;
vector[ y ] = z;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another example:

```
(which ? x : y) = 10;
```